# Clarify or delete the "advice" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

By definition, almost all questions here ask about advice. [Some questions are tagged "advice"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice), some aren't. I suggest that the "advice" tag is not useful and should be deleted.

One alternative would be to explicitly define the "advice" tag as

> This is a question about **giving, requesting or receiving** advice.

For instance, [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16436/how-to-advise-a-student-looking-for-an-under-grad-thesis-topic) could be tagged "advice" under this definition.

However, I am afraid that many users will nevertheless tag any request for advice with "advice", i.e., that the tag will have a low signal-to-noise ratio. In addition, out of the 17 questions currently tagged "advice", it seems like only the single one linked above asks for advice about giving advice, so after cleaning up useless instances of the tag, we would be left with only a single valid instance.

EDIT: And I would also propose deleting the [personal-advice](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-advice) tag, for exactly the same reason. (Should I split this off into a separate meta question?)

Comment: In preparation for deleting this tag, I have retagged all questions that were tagged *only* with "advice" or "personal-advice", so that removing these tags won't create untagged questions.

Comment: What about this question? The question needs advice tag or kind of its synonym tag. [How to advise a student looking for an under-grad thesis topic?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16436/how-to-advise-a-student-looking-for-an-under-grad-thesis-topic)

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect example of a [meta-tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93669/please-kill-some-meta-tags), and I think it should definitely be blacklisted. If there are others that should also be torched please add to the list.

Comment: +1 indeed, the site is about giving advice, right? It is as ridiculous as [tag:academia] would be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for deleting bad tags. However, there is a caveat that we should check if any of these tags should have been assigned to [advising](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advising) instead. Then the remaining can be "nuked" as needed.

Comment: There does not seem to be an [tag:advising] tag, but an [tag:advisor] one. Looking at the 17 questions tagged [tag:advice], none of these appear to be in need of retagging [tag:advisor].